# Bootstrap Card / Card-columns Breaking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming, multiple-columns

I need help solving this puzzle.
When using card-columns and cards in bootstrap 4.1, the row breaks when I don't want it to. I have column-count set to 4, and when there are 4 cards it looks perfect. When the fifth card is added it breaks the row to 3 cards on top and 2 below. Does anyone know of a fix for this. I have included a screenshot of all my rows below, Broke into 2 sections. Second section "Transitional", is where the issue is currently occurring.

I have played around with making the widows and orphans set to unset, but that didn't work. Cards are set to inline-block.

My Code is here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/alecruckus/1savgxjm/10/

```
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please, add also your code. Only with an image, it is impossible to help you to find the problem.

Comment: Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/alecruckus/1savgxjm/10/

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find the "problem": https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

> Cards can be organized into Masonry-like columns with just CSS by
>   wrapping them in .card-columns. Cards are built with CSS column
>   properties instead of flexbox for easier alignment. **Cards are ordered
>   from top to bottom** and left to right.

If there is space, cards are FIRST ordered from top to bottom, THEN left to right. You can understand exactly the order using numbers (*I used the default Boostrap column-count*):

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>First Set of 4</h1>
  <div class="card-columns">
    <!-- Cabinet 1 -->
    <div class="card">
      <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
      <p>Color <b>1</b></p>
      <p>Model</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Cabinet 2 -->
    <div class="card">
      <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
      <p>Color <b>2</b></p>
      <p>Model</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Cabinet 3 -->
    <div class="card">
      <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
      <p>Color <b>3</b></p>
      <p>Model</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Cabinet 4 -->
    <div class="card">
      <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
      <p>Color <b>4</b></p>
      <p>Model</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Second Set of 5</h1>
  <div class="card-columns">
    <!-- Cabinet 1 -->
    <div class="card cabinet">
      <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
      <p>Color <b>1</b></p>
      <p>Model</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Cabinet 2 -->
    <div class="card cabinet">
      <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
      <p>Color <b>2</b></p>
      <p>Model</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Cabinet 3 -->
    <div class="card cabinet">
      <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
      <p>Color <b>3</b></p>
      <p>Model</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Cabinet 4 -->
    <div class="card cabinet">
      <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
      <p>Color <b>4</b></p>
      <p>Model</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Cabinet 5 -->
    <div class="card cabinet">
      <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
      <p>Color <b>5</b></p>
      <p>Model</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

So, your code have no problem: it is the correct work of `column-count`: if the cards are many, you do not notice the "problem" of empty space.

If you want a row-direction disposition (i.e FIRST left to right, THEN top to bottom), you could use the normal `col-xx-xx` bootstrap class:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <h1>First Set of 4</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!-- Cabinet 1 -->
            <div class="card cabinet mb-3">
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
                <p>Color <b>1</b></p>
                <p>Model</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!-- Cabinet 2 -->
            <div class="card cabinet mb-3">
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
                <p>Color <b>2</b></p>
                <p>Model</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!-- Cabinet 3 -->
            <div class="card cabinet mb-3">
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
                <p>Color <b>3</b></p>
                <p>Model</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!-- Cabinet 4 -->
            <div class="card cabinet mb-3">
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
                <p>Color <b>4</b></p>
                <p>Model</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Second Set of 5</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!-- Cabinet 1 -->
            <div class="card cabinet mb-3">
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
                <p>Color <b>1</b></p>
                <p>Model</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!-- Cabinet 2 -->
            <div class="card cabinet mb-3">
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
                <p>Color <b>2</b></p>
                <p>Model</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!-- Cabinet 3 -->
            <div class="card cabinet mb-3">
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
                <p>Color <b>3</b></p>
                <p>Model</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!-- Cabinet 4 -->
            <div class="card cabinet mb-3">
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
                <p>Color <b>4</b></p>
                <p>Model</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!-- Cabinet 5 -->
            <div class="card cabinet mb-3">
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/S-1-1.png" alt="">
                <p>Color <b>5</b></p>
                <p>Model</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```